# HTML: what is this variable in curly braces? I never saw it before

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables

Can somebody tell what variable is this **{traveler.iFare}** ? As far as i know this is not PHP one, and in project where i found it there is no template engines used.

```
<td class="t-r">
    <span class="no-br p-l5">
        <strong>
            {traveler.iFare}
            {traveler.sCurrency}
        </strong>
    </span>
</td>
```

I want to call JavaScript function with 'iFare' as a parameter, but cant understand how

```
<script>
    document.write(window.functions.function(param));
</script>
```

Comment: it could be coming from a javascript framework too

Comment: looks like it could be a mustache template... is it wrapped in script tags?

Comment: DevZer0 was right, page is rendered via JS

Comment: Seems to be coming form a JavaScript templating Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's structured code templating.

Read **[This](http://handlebarsjs.com/)**

It should give you an idea of how to use it in HTML

Comment: When writing answers, try to make use of Markdown to format it better. Also, please write proper English (as in, capital letters, punctuation, etc).

Answer (score 1):

In order to the the value of the iFare. The simple script can do it very well

```
var iFare = traveler.iFare
```

and use it as you wish. This can be done because the `{traveler.iFare}` comes from a templating engine and after analysing this I can tell that the `traveler.iFare` is a simple JSON object which has a value `iFare` associated.